# Why I'm unable to invoke Java methods from html content via the JavaScript call in JavaFX WebView?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

I'm working on a task which needs to invoke a java method from a html content. This is a swing application and I used JavaFX WebView to load the HTML content into the application. But when I tried to invoke the Java methods it didn't work and sometime its giving fatal error and crashes the application.

Java class

```
class Solution extends JFrame { 
    
private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
static JFrame f; 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Solution().createUI();
}

    private void createUI() {
f = new JFrame("panel"); 

JPanel p = new JPanel(); 

jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
createScene();
p.add(jfxPanel);

f.add(p);
f.setSize(300, 300); 
f.show(); 
    } 
    
    private void createScene() {
        
PlatformImpl.setImplicitExit(false);
PlatformImpl.runAndWait(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
WebView webComponent = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = webComponent.getEngine();

webEngine.load(TestOnClick.class.getResource("/mypage.html").toString());

borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane,300,300);
jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
window.setMember("app", new Solution());
}
});
}
    
    public void onClick() {
        System.out.println("Invoked from JS");
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="app.onClick()">Click ME</button>
```

Please let me know what needs to be changed here

Comment: can you post the exact error you are getting and how are you testing this?

Comment: Your `Solution` class needs to be `public`. (See the "Calling back to Java from Javascript" section of the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html). Also note the requirements for modular applications.) Probably OT, but you should not use the `PlatformImpl` class. Use `Platform.setImplicitExit(...)` and `Platform.runLater(...)`. And you should invoke `createUI()` on the AWT Event Dispatch thread with `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. But as suggested, post the complete error (stack trace) for a precise solution.

Comment: @James_D thanks for your suggestion. I think incorporating those changes it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html), both the class and method used for the callback must be `public`:

> **Calling back to Java from JavaScript**
>
> The JSObject.setMember method is useful to enable upcalls from
>   JavaScript into Java code, as illustrated by the following example.
>   The Java code establishes a new JavaScript object named app. This
>   object has one public member, the method exit.
>
> ```
> public class JavaApplication {
>     public void exit() {
>         Platform.exit();
>     }
> }
> ...
> JavaApplication javaApp = new JavaApplication();
> JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
> window.setMember("app", javaApp);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ***The Java class and method must both be declared public.***

(My emphasis.)

Your `Solution` class is not public, so this won't work.

In addition, when a new document is loaded, the `window` will lose its attributes. Since loading happens asynchronously, you need to ensure the member is set on the window after the document loads. You can do this via a listener on the `documentProperty()`:

```
    webEngine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
        JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
        window.setMember("app", this);          
    });

    webEngine.load(Solution.class.getResource("/mypage.html").toString());
```

There are a number of other problems with your code:

1. `JFrame`s must be constructed on the AWT event dispatch thread (the same rule also applies to modifying components displayed in a `JFrame`). You can do this by wrapping the call to `createUI()` in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`.
2. It is unclear why you made `Solution` a subclass of `JFrame`, *as well as* creating a new `JFrame` in `createUI()`. Since you never use the fact that `Solution` subclasses `JFrame`, you should remove that.
3. `PlatformImpl` is not part of the public API: consequently it would be perfectly OK for the JavaFX team to remove that class in a later release. You should use methods in the `Platform` class.
4. You almost certainly want the Javascript callback to interact with the current `Solution` instance, not some arbitrary instance you create. (If you're in an inner class, use `Solution.this` to access the current instance of the surrounding object.)

A working version of your code is

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import netscape.javascript.JSObject;

public class Solution  {

    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Solution()::createUI);
    }



    private void createUI() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("panel");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        createScene();
        p.add(jfxPanel);

        f.add(p);
        f.setSize(300, 300);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createScene() {

        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
            WebView webComponent = new WebView();
            WebEngine webEngine = webComponent.getEngine();

            webEngine.documentProperty().addListener((obs, oldDoc, newDoc) -> {
                JSObject window = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                window.setMember("app", this);          
            });

            webEngine.load(Solution.class.getResource("/mypage.html").toString());

            borderPane.setCenter(webComponent);
            Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 300);
            jfxPanel.setScene(scene);

        });
    }

    public void onClick() {
        System.out.println("Invoked from JS");
    }

}
```